# Volume of Water In a Convex Pipe is $\propto$ $h$ iff the Pipe is Rectangular?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Suppose you have a straight pipe of length $L$ whose cross section $S$ is convex. Now suppose the pipe is horizontal and filled up to height $h$. If the pipe is square with sides of length $H$ and $L$, then the volume of the water in pipe is linear in the height of the water in the pipe since:

$$ V(h)= LWh \propto h$$

Is it true that if the cross section of the pipe is not rectangular then the volume of water in the pipe will always be non-linear in $h$?

That is, is it true that

$$V(h) \propto h \iff S \space Rectangular$$

I have no full proof for this and my approach appears inelegant: to divide the cross section into quarters and argue that the top and bottom quarters must be symmetric to be linear, to define the structure of the pipe as a function $f(x)$ and then define 'rectangular' as $f(x)=c$ and presumably show that for any $f(x) \neq c$ the derivative of $V_f(h)$ w.r.t. $h$ is not constant.

Comment: Hi Steve, the volume is proportional to the height if and only all the sections have constant area.  So, for instance, a cylinder like a keg would work.  Now a whiskey barrel , no, since it has a bigger midsection.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the word "convex" for the moment, the volume will be proportional to $h$ as long as the area is constant.  Since we assume the length of the pipe is constant, the width needs to be constant, too.  As long as the sides are "parallel curves"-the same curve offset by the width, the volume will be proportional to $h$.

Now we worry about "convex".  If one of the sides is concave toward the center of the pipe, the other one will be concave outwards.  This is not allowed, so the sides must be straight.  Nothing forces them to be vertical, however, so a pipe with a parallelogram cross section with one face parallel to the ground will meet the requirement as well.